# Traceback for Raspberry Pi Distance sensor

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am using the code below for Distance sensing using Pi

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

TRIG = 23 
ECHO = 24

print "Distance Measurement In Progress"

GPIO.setup(TRIG,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ECHO,GPIO.IN)

GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
print "Waiting For Sensor To Settle"
time.sleep(2)

GPIO.output(TRIG, True)
time.sleep(0.00001)
GPIO.output(TRIG, False)

while GPIO.input(ECHO)==0:
  pulse_start = time.time()

while GPIO.input(ECHO)==1:
  pulse_end = time.time()

pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start

distance = pulse_duration * 17150

distance = round(distance, 2)

print "Distance:",distance,"cm"

GPIO.cleanup()
```

The error that I am getting is:

1 ) It runs properly if there is no object

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ sudo python DS.py
Distance Measurement In Progress
Waiting For Sensor To Settle
Distance: 2334.34 cm
```

2) Here it gives error when i put an object in between :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ sudo python DS.py
Distance Measurement In Progress
Waiting For Sensor To Settle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DS.py", line 53, in <module>
    pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start
NameError: name 'pulse_start' is not defined
```

Comment: Then how does it run in the first instance

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are no declaring the variables, and if the code never pass by the while, the variable will never be declared, give a try with the code bellow:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

TRIG = 23
ECHO = 24

def configure_gpio():
  global TRIG, ECHO
  GPIO.setup(TRIG,GPIO.OUT)
  GPIO.setup(ECHO,GPIO.IN)
  GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
  print "Waiting For Sensor To Settle"
  time.sleep(2)

def take_measurement():
  global TRIG, ECHO
  pulse_start = pulse_end = 0

  print "Distance Measurement In Progress..."

  GPIO.output(TRIG, True)
  time.sleep(0.00001)
  GPIO.output(TRIG, False)

  while GPIO.input(ECHO)==0:
    pulse_start = time.time()

  while GPIO.input(ECHO)==1:
    pulse_end = time.time()

  pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start

  distance = pulse_duration * 17150

  distance = round(distance, 2)

  return distance

if __name__ == "__main__":
  configure_gpio()
  distance = take_measurement()

  print "The distance is: ", distance, "cm"
```

I'm not sure, if this will sove your problem, but I think may help you

Comment: Hey Thanks for the code. The issue was with Distance sensor .I replaced and it worked fine then . Thnks again